# appropriate shrad-key for mongodb collection

Tags: java, database, mongodb, key, sharding

i am developing an application that stores films and users data using mogo db, each user can see the user,s comments on a particular film , to be more precise the app will show the 10 more recent comments on this film , then the user can load more 10 comments by pressing a button and so on(there is a sort and skip aggregation on the query ). i have 6 (machines)servers and i want to use replication and sharing to improve the performance of the read/write operations. especilally i want to distribute  comments on the available shards to speed up the load comments query(it sorts and take the 10 more recent comments , then the 20 more recent and so on ) .each document of the comments collection has the following attributes:

```
_id:ObjectId(""),
film_id: Object_id(""),
author:"",
text:"",
date:,
type:"", //the source of the comment (IMDB,Mymovies)
comment_points:,//how much likes the comment has
user_rating:
```

i have read some articles  about he topic, i deducted that a key (high cardinality , low frequency, non monotonic value ) must be chosen .my question is : what is the best shard-key in my case ?
i am oriented to choose the film_id to speed up the read operations , but i am worrying that this will effect the work of the mongodb balancer